# Accessing newly added tracks in iTunes with COM interface

Tags: javascript, com, itunes

I am trying to add track information to newly added tracks in iTunes using the COM interface and JavaScript. I am able to successfully add files, but am unable to grab them using OperationStatus.Tracks(). I know that OperationStatus.Tracks() is unavailable until after OperationStatus.InProgress() returns false. However, when I try to call InProgress() on what I expect to be an OperationStatus object, I receive the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

```
var iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
var status = iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist.AddFile('newfile.mp4');
WScript.Echo(status.InProgress());
```

Can anyone shed some light on to what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since been able to answer my own question. I was simply adding empty parens when no parameters were necessary. As such, the methods and properties were not being recognized. The last line mentioned above will work in the following form:
`WScript.Echo(status.InProgress);`
To access the tracks that have been recently added can be done using
 `var newtracks = status.Tracks;`
 Then to access properties about an individual track can be done as follows:
 `var newtrack = newtracks.ItemByName('filename');`
`WScript.Echo(newtrack.Name);`

Comment: I was wondering how you were able to set up the javascript to access itunes, I have the itunes sdk but its a .h and .c file (which are source files for c type languages).  I'm trying to use javascript running on a local html file to get the now playing info from iTunes and display it on the page. (this is all on the local computer)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the result from the AddFile is asynchronous, so you will need to loop and wait before you can access the data.

```
var results = iTunesApp.AddFile( filepath );

// wait for the result to be available
while( results.InProgress )
    Thread.Yield(); 

foreach( var it in results.Tracks )
{
    tune = it as IITFileOrCDTrack;
    Console.WriteLine( "Track '{0} - {1}' was added to itunes library", tune.Artist, tune.Name );
}
```

To get the latest added tracks, i guess you could create a smart playlist, sorted by the added date and access cycle through, this will probably be faster than accessing the whole itunes DB.

Comment: sorry didn't realise the question was in javascript... still i guess this is still a valid point